# Using a recursive function to encrypt user input

Tags: c++, recursion, encryption

I’m trying to encrypt user input by using a recursive function to do so. I’m having trouble doing this and have been trying for som time. Any help to get me in the right path is appreciated. I have included the comments in my recursive function that must be completed in that order.

1. Get ascii code of first letter by casting char to int
2. Shift the ascii code by adding 3
3. Convert the ascii code to a character by casting into to char
4. Return the decrypted char + a recursive call to decrypt the next char

Comment: Didn't get what you actually want, If you want code for your pseudo algorithm then this is not correct platform to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to implement a Caesar cipher. Not really sure why you would want a recursive function when a simple looping will do.

```
string Encrypt(string plain){
    if(plain == "") return "";
    char encryptedLetter = (char)(plain[0] + 3);
    return encryptedLetter + Encrypt(plain.erase(0,1));
}
```

Here is a simple implementation of what you are looking for. You will need to take care of overflows yourself ('z' + 3).